# Convert US Date To UK Date Format C#

Tags: c#, date-formatting

All,

I'm really new to C# after years of VBA Programming. I have made an attempt at trying to convert a US date which is passed into the script via a parameter into a UK date. (Apologies if this is a really basic question - I am still working through training materials)

The issue I am having is passing the UK date out as a parameter.

Code below:

```
using System.Globalization;

namespace Dynamic.Script_8D643DCA79B170B
{
// Please use caution when modifying class name, namespace or attributes
[OpenSpan.TypeManagement.DynamicTypeAttribute()]
[OpenSpan.Design.ComponentIdentityAttribute("Script-8D643DCA79B170B")]
public sealed class Program
    {
    public void Dateformat(Datetime USdate, Datetime UKdate)
        {
        string value = USdate;
        string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
            {
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(format));
            }
        else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Date invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I would like to pass a date formatted as MM/dd/YYYY into the script and convert it into UK date format dd/MM/YYYY as a variable. Any help and guidance on how to adapt the above script would be much appreciated.

*****Edit**********

Thanks for all your help and advice so far, I have been able to develop a new script see below:

```
    public string Dateformat(string USdate)
    {
        string date = USdate; // en-US formatted date
        // Convert to DateTime
        DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        // Output in en-GB format

        return parsedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
```

The issue I am having with the above script is that the string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. See screenshot:

[image]

The USdate I am passing into the script is formatted in DateTime.

Comment: Why are you passing around `string`s instead of `DateTime` instances? What is the caller of this method and can it work with the `DateTime` type?

Comment: I agree with Igor. You really want to stay away from strings when it comes to `DateTime` - it will only get you in trouble.

Comment: You parse in a format and the Write it in the same format.. `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));`

Comment: What's the `String UKdate` parameter?

Comment: btw: For parsing or formatting `mm` is minutes and `MM` is months, the casing matters. Also if you do proceed with strings you want your method to **return** a string. So the signature would be `string MethodName(string input)`

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the advice I have adapted the orginal and changed String to DateTime. Plus changed the formatting of the "mm"

Comment: @DragandDrop I would like the UKdate parameter be the result of the US date passing through the script. However unsure how to make it the result.

Comment: Methods that do work and return a result should return the result, not make an out parameter. Declare your method as `public DateTime ConvertUsaToUK(DateTime inp)`

Comment: I don't understand your approach. Datetimes don't have a format, strings that look like dates have a format. Once you have converted a string to a datetime it represents an instant in time and can be reformatted at will. There's no such thing as a "USA" datetime, or a "UK" datetime. Sure your datetime might internally know what UTC moment it is and a time zone that indicates uk/USA so a local time representation can be printed but it doesn't make it a "USA" or "uk" datetime. Just parse the string to a datetime and keep it as a datetime, and format it to local string when you need

Comment: That's an [Out parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier), your are missing the Keyword.

Comment: In response to your edit, the only way you’ll get that message when trying to parse a string as a date is if it’s not actually in MM/dd/yyyy format. Whatever value you’re trying to parse, isn’t in the format you think it is

Comment: For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zuzld4

Comment: You should try [TryParseExact](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zuzld4). It works like ParseExact but it returns a boolean variable that tells you if the conversion was succesfull. Also, the last parameter is an out parameter that gets the DateTime value.